# Flutter - Error in BuildSuggestions (Search Delegate) using Firestore instance

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some problems with buildSuggestions. When I type something, it shows "Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot' " instead of the name of documents, like this image below.

Here is my code:

```
@override
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {


  return StreamBuilder(

    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("anuncios").where("caseSearch", arrayContains: query).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (query.isNotEmpty);

      List<DocumentSnapshot> results = snapshot.data.documents.where(
              (DocumentSnapshot a) => a.data["titulo"].toString().contains(query)).toList();

      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: results.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){


            return ListTile(
              onTap: (){
                close(context, results[index].toString());
              },
              title: Text(results[index].toString()),
            );
          }
      );

    },

  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your `snapshot.data.documents.where(...)` returns a `QuerySnapshot` object, which cannot be converted to a list of `DocumentSnapshot` by doing a `.ToList()` after it.

What you have to do is use the `docs` property of that `QuerySnapshot` object, which is exactly what you want, a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`. So applyin that to your code, you just have to replace the mentioned line for this:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> results = (snapshot.data.documents.where((DocumentSnapshot a) => a.data["titulo"].toString().contains(query))).docs;
```